# AVAudioPlayer crashing on ipad simulator but working fine on iPhone simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, avaudioplayer

This is very odd, my app works fine on the iPhone (simulator and device) but crashes on the ipad simulator. The error always points to the prepareToPlay method. When i took that method off it then points to the play method. The debug area does not show any errors or warnings. My only lead is the method tree but i can't figure out a solution. By the way audio files are mp3

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

_***viewDidLoad*__**

NSError *error = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
    //AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

```
timerSong = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:alarmSong error:&error];

[self loadSongTitles];

//Make sure the system follows our playback status
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
//infinite loops
audio1.numberOfLoops = -1;
audio2.numberOfLoops = -1;
timerSong.numberOfLoops = -1;

//set volume according to volume label
[audio1 setVolume:0.5];
[audio2 setVolume:0.5];
//strat playing track(s)
[audio1 play];
[audio2 play];
```

***loadSongsTitles***

```
for (NSNumber *number in passingArray) {
    //set the correct titles for each audio
    if (number == [NSNumber numberWithInt:10]) {
        firstSong = title;
        NSURL *audioFileLocationURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:[backgroundTracks objectAtIndex:firstSong] withExtension:@"mp3"];
        audio1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileLocationURL error:&error];
        [audio1 setDelegate:self]; //setting delagate to restart after interruptions
        [audio1 prepareToPlay];
        audio1Label.text = [titles objectAtIndex:title];
        //when two songs selected make label empty
        onlyOneAudioLabel.text = @"";
    }
```

Update: I've got it working, just use WAV files instead of mp3 and it just works. No idea why. Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

Found a permanent solution. You can use mp3's for both iPhone and iPad but you have to be very careful with the bit rates. I just set both bit rates as "normal" (~128kbits/s) and it works.
Hope this helps.